# How do I add ad permissions for an Expo project where there is no manifest file?

Tags: expo, google-play, ads

I want to use ads on my Google Play app and when I create a new release Google Play Console says that I need to add "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" to the manifest file. I am using Expo so there is no manifest file in my project. How would I go about fixing this? Is this possible with Expo?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After more searching I think I've found the answer. All I needed to do was add the permissions under android in the app.json file.

```
"android": {
"permissions": ["com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"],
}
```